# JavaScript Logic Guide

Tags: javascript

I have small function logically output should be 1 but i am getting 10 .. Can any one help me out with this logic.

```
var a=1;
function foo() {
    if(!a){
        var a=10;
    }
    console.log(a);
}
foo();
```

Output is coming 10 not 1 . how.

Comment: I would suggest trying to do some research on your own first.

Comment: You have 2 variables named `a`. Why?

Comment: @Lexi- that is the question . if i have a then dnt go in if condition , if not a is declare then declare a ..

Comment: Remove the `var` part and you get the output you are expecting

Answer (score 4):

It's because of something called "hoisting".

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

JS interpret your code like this

```
var a=1;
function foo(){
  var a;
  if(!a){
    a=10;
  }
  console.log(a);
}
foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) as mentioned in other answers, keep in mind that when writing ES6 (by using `let` or `const`) your code will behave as you expect it to.

Why does this happen? Because `let` and `const` have block-level scoping and not function-level scoping.

```js
let a = 1;

function foo() {
  if (!a) {
    let a = 10;
  }
  console.log(a);
}

foo();
```

This is why, when you use a JavaScript linting mechanism, like ESLint, you will see rules like `vars-on-top` ( https://eslint.org/docs/rules/vars-on-top ) specifically to avoid these types of issues.